# Multiple similar entries in ssh config

Tags: ssh

Say I want to configure my `ssh` options for 30 servers with the same setup in my `.ssh` `config` file:

```
host XXX
     HostName XXX.YYY.com
     User my_username
     Compression yes
     Ciphers arcfour,blowfish-cbc
     Protocol 2
     ControlMaster auto
     ControlPath ~/.ssh/%r@%h:%p
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/YYY/id_rsa
```

where the only thing that changes between these 30 machines is `XXX`.

Instead than repeating the above structure 30 times in my `config` file, is there another way to define a range of machines?

Answer (score 357, accepted):

From the `ssh_config(5)` man page:

> ```
>  Host    Restricts the following declarations (up to the next Host key‐
>          word) to be only for those hosts that match one of the patterns
>          given after the keyword.  If more than one pattern is provided,
>          they should be separated by whitespace.
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
>  HostName
>          Specifies the real host name to log into.  This can be used to
>          specify nicknames or abbreviations for hosts.  If the hostname
>          contains the character sequence ‘%h’, then this will be replaced
>          with the host name specified on the commandline (this is useful
>          for manipulating unqualified names).
> ```

So:

```
Host XXX1 XXX2 XXX3
  HostName %h.YYY.com
```

Comment: It appears the `%h` feature appeared in [release 5.6 of OpenSSH](http://www.openssh.com/txt/release-5.6).  I was wondering why I hadn't seen it before - the version in Debian Squeeze is 5.5.

Comment: If you're on an old OS or need rules that are not supported in `config`, you can always just write a simple script that generates your `config`.

Answer (score 187):

To minimize the setup you can have a `.ssh/config` like this one

```
Host X01
    HostName X01.YYY.com

Host X02
    HostName X02.YYY.com

...

Host X01 X02 ...
     User my_username
     Compression yes
     Ciphers arcfour,blowfish-cbc
     Protocol 2
     ControlMaster auto
     ControlPath ~/.ssh/%r@%h:%p
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/YYY/id_rsa
```

`Host X01 X02 ...` could be replace by `Host *` if every host have the following configuration

Comment: This seems to be the only answer that actually helps the OP (and myself).

Comment: What is the priority order? Is it just stuff defined later in the file overrides stuff defined earlier in the file? Like say I had "Compression no" under "Host X01", would that then be overridden by "Compression yes" under "Host X01 X02"?

Comment: From the ssh_config manual:

Since the first obtained value for each parameter is used, more host-specific declarations should be given near the beginning of the file, and general defaults at the end.

Comment: Can `Host X01 X02 ...` be replaced by `*.YYY.com`? That seems slightly more manageable if it works.

Comment: I combined this answer with the one using `%h` and it works as a charm (I only had one hostname that needed to use an alias because too long.

Answer (score 69):

Simply use `*`

See `man ssh_config`:

> PATTERNS
>        A pattern consists of zero or more non-whitespace characters, ‘*’ (a wildcard that matches zero or more characters), or ‘?’
>        (a wildcard that matches exactly one character).  For example, to specify a set of declarations for any host in the “.co.uk”
>        set of domains, the following pattern could be used:

```
       Host *.co.uk

 The following pattern would match any host in the 192.168.0.[0-9] network range:

       Host 192.168.0.?

 A pattern-list is a comma-separated list of patterns.  Patterns within pattern-lists may be negated by preceding them with an
 exclamation mark (‘!’).  For example, to allow a key to be used from anywhere within an organisation except from the “dialup”
 pool, the following entry (in authorized_keys) could be used:

       from="!*.dialup.example.com,*.example.com"
```

Comment: Thanks! That seems to be what I need, but I still don't understand how to adapt it to my case. Do I use a question mark `?` wherever I want it to be replaced by the pattern matched by the  `*` sign?

Comment: Hmm. I think patterns serves a different purpose from what I need. They redirect multiple queries to the same `config` entry, but the parameters of the Host are fixed (i.e. patterns cannot be used to *template* the parameters). Am I wrong?

Comment: @user27915816 Yes, you are right, there is no way to do "templates" as far as I know.  The best you can do is separate out the constant lines into a single `Host *` entry, and have a separate entry for each `Host XXX` that consists only of the parts that vary (i.e. the `Hostname XXX.YYY.ZZZ` line).

Comment: This page is the top result (for now) when Googling "ssh config wildcards", so thanks for providing an answer that addresses that question.

Comment: For multiple hosts/patterns use `Host a b c`. Joining them with commas, as the doc snippet shows, will not work for the Host declaration.

Answer (score 19):

From Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams and H.-Dirk Schmitt's answers, one can add the following to .ssh/config

```
HOST XXX*
    HostName %h.YYY.com
    User myname
```

and then, for example, you can login as myname@XXX2.YYY.com by

```
ssh XXX2
```

Comment: since XXX* implies XXX.YYY.com already, HostName should only be `%h`, not `%h.YYY.com`

Comment: @biocyberman `XXX*` implies `XXX.YYY.com` if and only if you type `ssh XXX2.YYY.com` instead of just `ssh XXX2`

Comment: If I'd like to add a prefix for these types of hosts, how could I remove the prefix from `%h`? For example, I'd like to use `ssh Company-Machine` to connect to `machine.worpskace.something` and `ssh Company-Boss` to `boss/worpskace.something`. The `%h` will be `company-machine` instead of `machine`.

Answer (score 11):

this works for me:

```
CanonicalizeHostname yes
CanonicalDomains xxx.auckland.ac.nz yyy.auckland.ac.nz

host  *.xxx.auckland.ac.nz
   user myuser
host *.yyy.auckland.ac.nz
   user myuser
```

this allows one to use names within the domain and have the username changed:

```
bluebottle:~ user_one$ ssh itslogprd05
myuser@itslogprd05.xxx.auckland.ac.nz's password:
```

Comment: This is the best answer for me. I got rid of the script I used to use to generate my config!

Comment: What if an `itslogprd05` host exists in both domains? `xxx.auckland.ac.nz` wins, I guess?

Answer (score 1):

The following way works.

```
Host 10.10.* 10.11.*
     User vagrant
```