# How can I alias a domain in .ssh/config?

Tags: ssh

I can alias individual hosts in .ssh/config like this:

```
Host nickname
    Hostname host1.example.com
```

But sometimes I want to alias a whole domain, so as to save typing on the command line for machines on that domain:

```
Host *.nick
    Hostname %h.really.long.domain.example.com
```

That doesn't work as written, of course. Is there something that would?

---

Comments have suggested [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61655) as a duplicate, but that solution doesn't work for this use case; it requires all hosts to be explicitly listed in the config file. I'm looking for a global method; I want to tell SSH 'rewrite *any* host of the form `host???.short` as `host???.really.long.example.com`.'

Think of it like an equivalent of `sed s/.short/.really.long.etc/`

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61655/multiple-similar-entries-in-ssh-config

Comment: The solution there does not work for this use case. (it requires listing all hosts on the domain in question).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no way to perform a replacement in that manner, but it is possible to use `CanonicalDomains` to append domains to a hostname before attempting to check if they exist.

```
CanonicalDomains really.long.domain.example.com
CanonicalizeHostname yes

Host *.really.long.domain.example.com
    AdditionalDirectives
```

Comment: Hrm. Wouldn't the block above have the same practical effect as `Host *`?

Comment: A bit disappointing that it can't be done as desired, but oh well, a negative answer is still an answer.

Comment: @Andrew: No, because `Host *` affects *all* arbitrary hosts whereas this only affects hosts that can be resolved to that FQDN.