# SSH Boxes Change Port Number

Tags: bash, centos, ssh, files, gnome-boxes

[image]I am trying to connect to a remote machine using boxes on centos7.  I enter `ssh://ip:port` which brings me to some usage: ssh screen with a blinking cursor that I am unable to exit out of.  Likely because I don't know the [code bro]

Do I have the syntax wrong?

[image]

Comment: Could you add some more details? How were the ssh port changed at the hosts boxes? Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55332816/how-to-set-vagrants-host-ssh-port#55333180

Comment: I expect if you specify `Host customname` in your `~/.ssh/config` with proper `HostName` and `Port` then you will be able to connect by giving the address as `ssh://customname`. Other connection parameters can also be specified in the file ([example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/61655/108618)). This is not an answer because I haven't tested (I don't use Gnome).

Comment: Are you trying to connect to a virtual machine running on another host?  Or just use gnome boxes to ssh into a remote host?

Answer (score 0):

The command from the command-line for ssh is simply `ssh HOST` or `ssh HOST:PORT` where `HOST` is an IP address or hostname.  The PORT defaults to 22 if not specified.

If you're stuck and can't exit, type `~.` (tilde period) to disconnect.  You may need to press enter before typing it to get to the beginning of the line.

This is documented in `man ssh` in the `ESCAPE CHARACTERS` section.

Comment: Note the [tag:gnome-boxes] tag.

Comment: unable to type ~

Answer (score 0):

This solved the issue

```
 ssh://userid@ipadd:port
```